# I have created a custom lookup field. But the records are not displayed in the related list of the parent object

Tags: custom-field, lookup, related-list, relationships, record

I have created a custom lookup field. But the records are not displayed in the related list of the parent object. Suggest me what needs to be modified or checked

Comment: It is hard to suggest with so little detail of what you've already done yourself. Is the related list visible on the parent page layout ?

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the related list to the page layout of the parent object, which you can do from the Setup | Create | Objects or Setup | Customize menu depending on whether it is a custom or standard object.

You can also specify the fields to display etc.